# K9s can't open because 'po' command not found

Tags: xcode, macos

I was using k9s during work and when I try to start it, I got the error message :

`Boom!! app run failed 'po' command not found.`

I searched for how to reinstall the 'po' command, but no useful information is found. I tried to re-install the xcode-select on my machine but still not working.

The config file of the k9s from my side looks like this

```
k9s:
  refreshRate: 2
  maxConnRetry: 5
  enableMouse: false
  headless: false
  logoless: false
  crumbsless: false
  readOnly: false
  noIcons: false
  logger:
    tail: 100
    buffer: 5000
    sinceSeconds: 60
    fullScreenLogs: false
    textWrap: false
    showTime: false
  currentContext: xxxx/yyyy
  currentCluster: xxxx/yyyy
  clusters:
    xxxx/yyyy:
      namespace:
        active: default
        favorites:
        - default
      view:
        active: po
      featureGates:
        nodeShell: false
      shellPod:
        image: busybox:1.31
        command: []
        args: []
        namespace: default
        limits:
          cpu: 100m
          memory: 100Mi
      portForwardAddress: localhost
  thresholds:
    cpu:
      critical: 90
      warn: 70
    memory:
      critical: 90
      warn: 70
  screenDumpDir: /var/folders/rl/_xgz4l291pq2ljx1p7x8l5sm0000gn/T/k9s-screens-name
```

I guess the problem is from the part of the config file

```
view:
        active: po
```

Could Someone help with this? thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

In k9s `config.yml`, I believe they are trying to save the last viewed command . If this is no longer valid, it fails. Ideally, this should be handled gracefully.

**Work around**

```bash
# edit config.yml
# following is Mac OS path. Equivalent paths in other OS
vim ~/Library/Application\ Support/k9s/config.yml
```

- find the erroring out command., In your case

```yaml
...
view:
     active: po

# change this to something generic
...
view:
     active: pods
```

- Save config.yml and try re-opening k9s

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:The problem is most likely with your `kubeconfig`

K9s communicates under the hood with clusters in a similar manner to how `kubectl` does, and whenever a `kubectl` command does not work; you get the same error in K9s. Hence, that error that you are seeing, means that you must have an issue accessing the cluster.

The `po` is short for `pods` and so what K9s is trying to do, is to run `kubectl get po` or rather `kubectl get pods` (in the current context/namespace), and this does not have anything to do with the K9s config file.

The `view` section of the config file tells K9s which window/tab to view when you start it (which is by default the last thing you had opened... in your case, it looks like you were viewing the pods)

So, to troubleshoot your issue follow these steps:

1. Check your `kubeconfig` file if it is correct (correct location, correct `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable, and correct contents). You can use `kubectl config view --raw` on a machine that has no trouble connecting to the cluster.
2. Check that you can access your cluster with `kubectl`; maybe you were using a token to access it and that token expired? or maybe you forgot to use the VPN used at your work? or any similar reasons.
3. Try accessing another cluster with K9s and see if you have the same issue. If you can, then the issue is either with your cluster or its `kubeconfig` file. You can also re-install your K9s and repeat this step.
4. Try accessing the cluster from another machine and see if you have the same issue. If you can, then the issue is with you machine, either with the network or the `kubeconfig` file

To conclude; there is no "reinstalling the 'po' command", and I don't think there is a need for any workaround. These are the troubleshooting steps that I'd follow if I had a similar issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

```
 > brew remove k9s
 > rm -rf /Users/home-folder/.config/k9s
 > rm -rf /Users/home-folder/Library/Application\ Support/k9s
 > brew install k9s
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and seems reporting the same error afterwards. Don't know how to reinstall this po command in macOS

Comment: These commands are actually bundled in, try this one > brew install derailed/k9s/k9s